# Open files with libGdx (android)?

Tags: javascript, java, android, libgdx

Can I open files (.apk) with libGdx?

I download an apk from the internet and then I want to open it.

MyCode:

```
public void download(){
    final Net.HttpRequest httpRequest = new Net.HttpRequest(Net.HttpMethods.GET);
    httpRequest.setUrl("http://singlepong.square7.ch/BirdColor.apk");
    httpRequest.setContent(null);
    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(httpRequest, new Net.HttpResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void handleHttpResponse(Net.HttpResponse httpResponse) {
            // Determine how much we have to download
            long length = Long.parseLong(httpResponse.getHeader("Content-Length"));

            // We're going to download the file to external storage, create the streams
            InputStream is = httpResponse.getResultAsStream();
            OutputStream os = Gdx.files.external("BirdColor.apk").write(false);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int count = -1;
            long read = 0;
            try {
                // Keep reading bytes and storing them until there are no more.
                while ((count = is.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length)) != -1) {
                    os.write(bytes, 0, count);
                    read += count;

                    // Update the UI with the download progress
                    final int progress = ((int) (((double) read / (double) length) * 100));
                    final String progressString = progress == 100 ? "Click to download" : progress + "%";

                    // Since we are downloading on a background thread, post a runnable to touch ui
                    Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run () {
                            if (progress == 100) {
                                button.setDisabled(false);
                            }
                            button.setText(progressString);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable t) {
            button.setText("Download failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() {

        }
    });
}
```

How can I then open the downloaded apk?

Sorry my English is not very good but I lern it only since one year.

I'm happy about helpful answers.  (:

Comment: What do you mean by open it?  An apk file is just a signed zip file, to open it you just need to rename it .zip and your OS should be able to handle it.

Comment: I mean that I want to open it with the application manager, so that you can directly install the app on your device.